# Looping in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure a way to loop this code so that it restarts once all three of the calculations are complete. I have figured a way to restart the program itself, however I can't manage to restart it so that it returns back to the first calculation step. Anyone can help a brother out? Thanks in advance.

The code that I have used to restart the program:

```
def restart_program():

python = sys.executable
os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    answer = input("Do you want to restart this program?")
    if answer.lower().strip() in "y, yes".split():
        restart_program()
```

My program without the restart code:

```
import math
import sys
import os


print ("This program will calculate the area, height and perimeter of the Triangles: Scalene, Isosceles, Equilateral and a Right Angled Triangle.")

# calculate the perimeter

print ("Please enter each side for the perimeter of the triangle")

a = float(input("Enter side a: "))
b = float(input("Enter side b: "))
c = float(input("Enter side c "))

perimeter = (a + b + c)

print ("The perimeter for this triangle is: " ,perimeter)


# calculate the area

print ("Please enter each side for the area of the triangle")

a = float(input("Enter side a: "))
b = float(input("Enter side b: "))
c = float(input("Enter side c "))

s = (a + b + c) / 2

sp = (a + b + c) / 2
area = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) ** 0.5    #area = math.sqrt(sp*(sp - a)*(sp - b)*(sp - c))#

print ("The area for this triangle is %0.2f: " %area)


# calculate the height

height = area / 2

print ("The height of this triangle is: ", height)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put everything in a while loop which could repeat forever or until a user types a certain phrase.

```
import math
import sys
import os


print ("This program will calculate the area, height and perimeter of the Triangles: Scalene, Isosceles, Equilateral and a Right Angled Triangle.")
while True:


    # calculate the perimeter

    print ("Please enter each side for the perimeter of the triangle")

    a = float(input("Enter side a: "))
    b = float(input("Enter side b: "))
    c = float(input("Enter side c "))

    perimeter = (a + b + c)

    print ("The perimeter for this triangle is: " ,perimeter)


    # calculate the area

    print ("Please enter each side for the area of the triangle")

    a = float(input("Enter side a: "))
    b = float(input("Enter side b: "))
    c = float(input("Enter side c "))

    s = (a + b + c) / 2

    sp = (a + b + c) / 2
    area = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) ** 0.5    #area = math.sqrt(sp*(sp - a)*(sp - b)*(sp - c))#

    print ("The area for this triangle is %0.2f: " %area)


    # calculate the height

    height = area / 2

    print ("The height of this triangle is: ", height)
```

or

```
while answer.lower() in ("yes", "y"):
    //code
    answer = input("Would you like to repeat?")
```

You could also put it all into a function `def main():` and then do some form of recursion (calling a function in itself).

Those are just a few ways. There are a ton of ways you can get what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Just Have the function loop on itself. Restarting the shell isn't necessary.

```
import math
import sys
import os

def calc():
    print ("This program will calculate the area, height and perimeter of the Triangles: Scalene, Isosceles, Equilateral and a Right Angled Triangle.")

    # calculate the perimeter

    print ("Please enter each side for the perimeter of the triangle")

    a = float(input("Enter side a: "))
    b = float(input("Enter side b: "))
    c = float(input("Enter side c "))

    perimeter = (a + b + c)

    print ("The perimeter for this triangle is: " ,perimeter)


    # calculate the area

    print ("Please enter each side for the area of the triangle")

    a = float(input("Enter side a: "))
    b = float(input("Enter side b: "))
    c = float(input("Enter side c "))

    s = (a + b + c) / 2

    sp = (a + b + c) / 2
    area = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) ** 0.5    #area = math.sqrt(sp*(sp - a)*(sp - b)*(sp - c))#

    print ("The area for this triangle is %0.2f: " %area)


    # calculate the height

    height = area / 2

    print ("The height of this triangle is: ", height)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        answer = input("Do you want to restart this program?")
        if answer.lower().strip() in "y, yes".split():
            calc()
        else:
            exit()


calc()
```

If the answer is yes, then the function is called and everything repeats. If the answer is not yes then the program exits.

Answer (score -2):

This should do.

```
def restart_program():

python = sys.executable
os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while input("Do you want to restart this program?").lower().strip() in "y, yes".split():
        restart_program()
```